# How to review a game in Steam library?

Tags: steam

I'm using Steam on Windows. How can I review a game? I remember previously I would right click the game in my library and choose 'write a review' but that option seems to be no longer there.

Comment: Note that reviewing is not available for all games; there must be a minimum play time limit required before you are allowed to review.

Answer (score 5):

If you scroll down on the game page in your library, there is a button that lets you post a review:

[image]

Alternatively, if you have played a game for some time but have yet to write a review, there is a feedback panel that leads to a review prompt page:

[image]

Which leads to:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can write a review for a game you own from the game's store page. You can reach the store page through the link under the install/play button on the game's entry in your library.

Answer (score 1):

**There is a minimum play time of 5 minutes before, on the store page, there appeared a big box asking for your review** just below the "This game is already in your library" message and "Play Now" button:

[image: screenshot of store page with arrow pointing to review box]

Search for the game here to get to this page: https://store.steampowered.com/search/

Took me a while to figure this out, as I've been playing with custom options (from the command line outside of Steam) such that it runs with my wonky driver situation. Somehow **Steam doesn't register that I've played the game at all.** Copying files to another computer doesn't work so there is some DRM active that checks that you're logged in with your account, but it still blocks you from reviewing. (I wonder if it has an effect on the 2-hour refund thing, but anyway that would be scummy to try out.)

**If you are in the same situation** and Steam literally cannot run the game to accumulate time, what worked for me is writing a few lines of Bash that finds the process ID as soon as Steam tries to launch it (via Proton) and does `kill -STOP $pid` immediately. Now go drink some water, and after 5 minutes you can `kill -CONT $pid` to let it crash and now you have enough time on the clock to write a review.

<sub>The screenshot is censored because I don't want this to seem like an advertisement, but the major graphic components are left in because I don't have placeholders and so that the page is recognisable at a glance.</sub>